# Extract Integers from file

Tags: haskell

If my file (csv) looks like this:

```
John,12323,New York, 2233
```

I read the file with:

```
contents <- readFile "data.csv"
```

My result is a `String` which I split with `splitOn`:

```
["John","12323","New York","2233"]
```

How can I filter only the numbers from this list?

```
filter (=~ "regex") resultList
```

I already tried it with the filter method but it does not work.

This is what I want to achieve:

```
[12323,2233]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a CSV parsing library like Cassava: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cassava

Among other things it has decoding for things like Integers built in with error handling.

I have a [7,000 word post here](http://howistart.org/posts/haskell/1) that is all about CSV parsing if you'd like examples.

Answer (score 4):

```
import Data.Char

isInteger = all isDigit

onlyIntegers :: [String] -> [Integer]
onlyIntegers = map read . filter isInteger
```

Comment: Please include an explanation as to why this answers the asker's question.  As it is, it may answer the question but offers little insight into why this helps the original asker or any future viewer of this question who may have the same issue.

Comment: @Josh Burgess, what should I explain here? It's just like in the **bheklilr**'s answer: "a relatively simple solution combining built-in functions". Even simpler and more self-describing (not nicer, however).

Answer (score 3):

You could use regex, but that's going to be error prone and slow.  You'd essentially have to parse each number twice.  Instead, you can use a relatively simple solution combining built-in functions:

```
import Text.Read (readMaybe)
import Data.Maybe (catMaybes)

extractInts :: [String] -> [Int]
extractInts = catMaybes . map readMaybe
```

A better solution would be to use a CSV parsing library like Cassava, in which you could write a data structure like

```
data MyRecord = MyRecord
    { name :: String
    , zipCode :: Int
    , city :: String
    , anotherField :: Int
    } deriving (Eq, Show)

instance FromRecord MyRecord where
    parseRecord v
        | length v == 4
            =   MyRecord
            <$> v .! 0
            <*> v .! 1
            <*> v .! 2
            <*> v .! 3
        | otherwise = mzero
```

Then you can use the `decode` functions in Cassava to parse your file for you more efficiently than `splitOn` will do.